# Do the second two White Sand graphic novels continue past the prose novel?

Tags: cosmere, white-sand

I know that the White Sand graphic novels adapt the original prose version. Do the second two continue the story or are they the prose split into three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The graphic novels are the prose version split into 3 parts. According to the Amazon description, this is the basic plot for volume 2

> Following the loss of most of his colleagues in a violent ambush, Kenton has become Lord Mastrell of the few remaining Sand Masters, magicians who can manipulate sand to do their bidding. With the ruling council poised against him, the hot-headed Kenton must become a diplomat to have any hope of preventing the eradication of his people forever.

I've read the prose version and this part of the story is definitely part of it, so volume 2 is well within the story the prose version tells.

Comment: thanks is there any word on a sequel?

Comment: @Antheloth In [his most recent State of the Sanderson blog post](https://brandonsanderson.com/state-of-the-sanderson-2018/), (a yearly event on Brandon's birthday where he talks about all of his work and his plans for future writing,) he wrote "I have no immediate plans to do sequels to [White Sand] in graphic novel form, though you can expect stories set on Taldain [the world in which White Sand takes place] to happen in the future."  I'm not aware of any more-specific details than that.  There will be more stories, at some undefined point in the future.